# How do I know that user is going to uninstall my app

Tags: android

Is this possible to know that user is going to uninstalling my application. Because I want to delete the folder that is created by my application. So for the task, I am not getting how to do that? Please help me.

Comment: follow this link :-> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15988592/when-i-uninstall-my-app-can-we-remove-my-folder-which-is-created-through-my-ap

Answer (score 0):

> Because I want to delete the folder that is created by my application

Save your data in the location returned by `getFilesDir()`. It will get cleared automatically by android system when your app got uninstalled. So you don't have to worry.

[see the official doc](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

Comment: Thanks, Darish, but I want to store in external sd card because of the large size of my app folder,- Your solution affect me to Insufficient space during the download of my data.